# Having trouble rebuilding planet logo

Tags: gimp, logo

I'm trying to recreate this logo in gimp, but I am having trouble with it, mainly the rings in particular.

Here is the image I am trying to recreate.

[image]

Any help/tips would be appreciated.

Methods I have tried so far:

- The first thing I tried was to use fuzzy select and then convert the selection to a path. This did not work well because the selection was not accurate enough.
- Next I wanted to try an additive/subtraction method using layers and groups.

  - I would start by creating an ellipse selection, shrink it down, then give it a border as to form a circle.
  - Next I would add two layers, one for each color. I would fill the entire selection with each color then add a mask to the layer to hide half of the circle, showing the other half.
  - Trying to rotate the layer to give it a tilt did not really work as it wasn't simple to adjust it (The mask would get in the way and not show the result until the rotate was applied).
  - I wasn't sure how I was going to build the rings in this manner, so this method did not seem like the best one to use.

Those were really the only two methods I tried because I wasn't sure of what the best solution would be after the second one failed. I figured I should ask for some help/advice to see what other methods there are.

Comment: Can you tell us what approaches you have tried, and how they failed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You recreate a path using the existing image as a guide:

[image]

But since logos are really [vector drawings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) ("paths" are Gimp's limited vector capability) you should use a vector graphics editor for this (typically, Inkscape).